# Templates - Passing variable instead of value

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template:

```
template<unsigned int N> struct IntN;

template <> struct IntN< 8> {
   typedef uint8_t type;
}; 

template <> struct IntN<16> {
   typedef uint16_t type;
};
```

And in main I initialise and alternate by doing this:

```
IntN< 8>::type c;
```

This seems to work, however, when I store the value inside a variable, it does not and I get the following error:

> error: non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression

Here is an example of the code:

```
template<unsigned int N> struct IntN;

template <> struct IntN< 8> {
  typedef uint8_t type;
};

template <> struct IntN<16> {
   typedef uint16_t type;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int foo = 8;

IntN<foo>::type c;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template arguments for integral template parameters must be constant expressions. An integral literal is a constant expression

```
IntN<8>::type c;
```

A constant variable initialized with a constant expression is a constant expression

```
const int n = 8;
IntN<n>::type c;
```

Here n is OK because it's both const and initialized by a constant expression (8). The following will not compile though:

```
int n = 8;
const int m = n;
IntN<n>::type c; //error n is not const therefore not a constant expression
IntN<m>::type c; //error m is const but initialized with a non-constant expression therefore not a constant expression
```

Comment: Hey, that's it! BUT I set the value somewhere else in the program, and, therefore it cannot be constant.. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1326876 If its value is determined run-time, there is just no way you can pass it as a template argument. Templates are instantiated compile-time

Answer (score 0):

A function template is a **blueprint** that tells the compiler **how** to generate code for the function **when** it is instantiated (i.e. when you use a template function in your code).

Exactly **what** the compiler will generate depends on the instantiated values of the template parameters.  These values have to be known and finalized by then, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what code to generate.